# Firebase dynamic links Rest API: Unknown name "socialMetaTagInfo"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to add some social meta tag info to my dynamic links, according to this doc:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

I have to add socialMetaTagInfo in my parameter.

But when I do so I'm getting error 400 with the following message:

> message: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   "socialMetaTagInfo": Cannot find field." status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

my code is the following:

```
var params = {
        "longDynamicLink": "https://myapp.page.link/?link=https://www.google.com",
        "socialMetaTagInfo": {
          "socialTitle": "test title",
          "socialDescription": "test description"
        },
        "suffix": {
          "option": "SHORT"
        }
      }

      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=MYAPIKEY',
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify(params),
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function (response) {
              console.log(response.shortLink);
          },
          error: function () {
              console.log("error");
          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = {
        "dynamicLinkInfo": "https://myapp.page.link",
        "link": "https://www.google.com",
        "socialMetaTagInfo": {
          "socialTitle": "test title",
          "socialDescription": "test description"
        },
        "suffix": {
          "option": "SHORT"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O. Do try and provide some textual description of your answer.